# Assign an individual core to a process

Tags: linux, cpu, process, cpu-usage, cpu-cores

What I'm trying to implement is to run a python script on it's own core on Raspberry Pi 2 with Debian. One can use `taskset` to bind a process to particular core. But I need this core to be free of OS's and other processes' load at the same time. How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps also set it to realtime priority?

Comment: @Leonidas I expanded my answer with some test resutls. Check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This whole thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149463) should be useful.

> I would look for a way to limit the 'init' process to running on cpu 1.

In general case the last words should be "running on all CPUs but 1". I guess one can use some [kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt); `irqaffinity`, `isolcpus` look promising.

---

#### EDIT:

About `isolcpus` in [kernel parameters documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt):

> This option is the preferred way to isolate CPUs. The alternative -- manually setting the CPU mask of all tasks in the system -- can cause problems and suboptimal load balancer performance.

I did some tests. Results:

- Kernel parameter `isolcpus` is the one you may use to limit the `init` process and isolate CPU(s).
- It seemed to me that kernel parameter `irqaffinity` did not affect isolated CPU(s). You probably don't need this parameter.
- When I isolated *CPU0* it didn't go completely idle. Is that system or hardware requirement to do some computation with it despite isolation? – I don't know.
- **When I isolated *CPU1* or *CPU7* it was <strike>solid as</strike> idle as a rock.**

To isolate *CPU1* add `isolcpus=1` in your `grub.cfg`, like this:
`linux /vmlinuz-`(…all your current parameters here…) `isolcpus=1`

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER CONTINUES:

> Alternatively, after the system has started, you can re-assign the affinity of all currently running processes, but that seems less elegant.

I agree it seems less elegant, yet it may work good enough (EDIT: it can cause problems and suboptimal load balancer performance, as stated above). There is quick and dirty one-liner that works in my Debian:

```
sudo bash -c 'cd /proc ; for i in [1-9]* ; do taskset -a -p fffffffe $i ; done'
```

I got errors for some *pid*s, nevertheless `htop` shows that one core is virtually idle after that. Of course you have to run your script later, exclude it somehow or simply reassign:

```
taskset -a -p 1 PID
```

I expect you won't need to repeat said one-liner to cover new processes since CPU affinity is inherited.

Answer (score 3):

With package Cpuset:

```
# cset shield -c 42 -k on
```

to reserve CPU #42 for your task (you can reserve a group of CPUs), then

```
# cset shield -e your_script
```

to start `your_script` on your reserved CPUs. (See also options `--user` and `--group`.)

When you're done, release CPUs ("reset the shield") with:

```
# cset shield -r
```

---

There is much, much more to this tool.
E.g., attaching a previously running process to the reserved CPU:

```
# cset shield -s -p <PID> --threads
```

Command-line help:

```
# cset help
```

[Online help/tutorial](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_Management_Utility/tutorial)

Comment: Looks promising. Can you expand your answer and post a command to release the reservation and return to default state?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: do you have any feedback to provide about the commands I added on your request?