# Force process and kernel module to one core exclusively

Tags: linux, cpu, kernel, multi-core

I'm just in the phase of evaluating new possibilities, so this question may be a bit strange. I have a Quad-Core CPU which has to do some realtime tasks (it has access to some GPIOs, so this is definitely possible). Instead of using a Realtime Linux (which is more a soft realtime), I want to implement a hard realtime application. So my idea is this:

- on bootup force all components of the operating system to two of the CPUs cores
- load one kernel module which uses the third core exclusively and therefore can do some nasty things like bit-banging the GPOs in realtime
- later start one process which uses the remaining core and sends data to the kernel module

My questions: is it possible to configure a Linux Kernel/System in this way? If yes: how can I ensure two cores are left unused and how can I put a kernel module and a process to them?

Every idea and hint is welcome :-)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/q/1082194/432690) as a starting point?

Comment: You may have also a look into `numactl`. There is a good blog entry about [process affinity](https://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html).